# grep/sed replace no match with blank space

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Example of a file I'm greping information in:

```
name : server1
description : webserver
memory : 32gb

name : server2
memory : 128gb

name : server3
description : appserver
```

I'm doing something like this :

```
cat myfile | egrep -w "name|description|memory" | awk -F" " '{print $3}' >> myfile2
```

In order to get back information from the second column in myfile.

Then, I format myfile2 to have information from each server on one line (using tr to replace CRLF), separated by semicolonn to import them on Excel.

```
myfile2:
server1;webserver;32gb
server2;128gb
server3;appserver
```

Problem is: when egrep doesn't match anything (like description for server2 or memory for server3), there is a gap of one row in myfile2... How can I replace it by a blank space?

Output wanted of my file2 :
server1;webserver;32gb
server2;;128gb
server3;appserver;;

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show us exactly what the desired output would be for the input you have shown?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you *really* trying to do here, and what will consume these data?  As Tom suggested, please provide examples of the variations of output you're looking for.

Comment: `grep -v "^$"` will exclude blank lines.

Comment: Post edited. When there is nothing to grep (like description for server2 or memory for server3) I just want at this moment to put a semicolon in order to create a row even if there is no information in it.

Comment: Where did "server3" come from in your expected output? Make sure the expected output matches the sample input.

Comment: My bad, I should use dot dot dot to say that in myfile there is a lot of other servers after server2.

So server3 is just another example where memory column doesn't match to grep because it's empty there.

Comment: No do NOT use `...`, that just obfuscates the question. Simply create a small, complete, precise, TESTABLE sample input and the associated expected output.

Comment: Understood :) I did it. And thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to use `grep` on your input data.  The `awk` command can do almost everything that `grep` can.  Consider the following:

```
awk -F' *: *' '
  {
    a[$1]=$2;
  }

  /^memory/ {
    printf("%s;%s;%s\n", a["name"], a["description"], a["memory"]);
    delete a;
  }' myfile
```

The components here are as follows:

- `-F...` sets your field delimiter, including whitespace.
- `a[$1]=$2` populates a short-lived array with the data from each record.
- `/^memory/` executes this recipe only on the last line of each group...
- `printf(...)` displays your output, and
- `delete a` lets you start fresh on the next multi-line record.

You could of course compact this all onto a single line:

```
awk -F' *: *' '{ a[$1]=$2 } /^memory/ { printf("%s;%s;%s\n", a["name"], a["description"], a["memory"]); delete a }' myfile
```

Is this what you need?

**UPDATE**

I see that you've modified your question to include sample data that is different from what the solution above supports.  Here's an update that should work with the current example:

```
function outp() {
        printf("%s;%s;%s\n", a["name"], a["description"], a["memory"]);
}

BEGIN {
        seen=0;
        FS=" *: *";
}

/^name/ && seen {
        outp();
        delete a;
}

/^name/ {
        seen=1;
}

{
        a[$1]=$2;
}

END {
        outp();
}
```

This uses a function (`outp()`) to simplify things.  It uses the `seen` variable to determine whether the script has seen any actual data yet (otherwise, the first match of `/^name/` would generate empty output).  And it continues to use the `a` array to collect the important fields.

It's important to note that now, instead of assuming you'll have a "memory" at the *end* of every record, we assume that you'll have a "name" at the *beginning* of every record.  If this assumption is incorrect, please specify how you think you should be able to tell records from each other (i.e. where does one stop and the next one start).  Blank lines are an option, for example.

Comment: And I've updated my answer to reflect the updated example data in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It SOUNDS like all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F' *: *|\n' -v OFS=';' '{print $2,$4,$6}' myfile
server1;webserver;32gb
server2;;128gb
```

If you want CRLF line endings then just tell awk that by adding `-v ORS='\r\n'` at the front.

Not sure why you haven't just updated your question yet but it sounds like this is what you really need:

```
$ cat file  
name : server1
description : webserver
memory : 32gb

name : server2
memory : 128gb

name : server3
description : appserver
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    RS=""
    FS=" *: *|\n"
    OFS=";"
    numNames = split("name description memory",names,/ /)
    for (i=1; i<=numNames; i++) {
        name2nr[names[i]] = i
    }
}
{
    delete vals
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        vals[name2nr[$i]] = $(i+1)
    }
    for (i=1; i<=numNames; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i<numNames?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
server1;webserver;32gb
server2;;128gb
server3;appserver;
```

It can be written to add a first pass that just figures out the field names instead of hard-coding them in the BEGIN section but then the output order of fields becomes dependent on the order in which they appear in the input so not sure it's worthwhile in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good to me :) But, I made a mistake in my example. In fact, when there is no data the field is hidden.

So for server2 :
`name : server2
memory : 128gb`

In the case of there is no description of server2.

That's why I'm doing a grep to begin. Because in your example print $4 become "128gb" when for another server it's the description.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by `when there is no data the field is hidden`. If your example is incorrect or incomplete then edit your question to provide a better example.

Comment: I mean if there is no description or no memory specified for a server, the field "description" or "memory" does not appear on the file. So it's not really like I described it in my first post.

Comment: OK then, again, update your post to be accurate so we can best help you and future readers of this Q&A.